# invoke synchronized static method,then can other static methods be accessed?

Tags: java

I have an question about synchronized static methods.
If i invoke a synchronized static method, does it mean i lock this class and other method (including static or no static) can not be accessed before the synchronized static method end?

When A synchronized static method is locking class object, why the other static method can be invoked at the same time?

```
class Y {
    static synchronized void staticSleep() {
        System.out.println("Start static sleep");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        System.out.println("End static sleep");
    }
    static void staticSleepNoSyn() {
        System.out.println("Start static NoSyn sleep");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        System.out.println("End static NoSyn sleep");
    }
} 

public class X {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    Y.staticSleep();
                }
            }).start();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    Y.staticSleepNoSyn();
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }
}
```

the output:

> Start static sleep
>   Start static NoSyn sleep
>   Start static NoSyn sleep
>   Start static NoSyn sleep
>   Start static NoSyn sleep
>   Start static NoSyn sleep
>   Start static NoSyn sleep
>   Start static NoSyn sleep
>   Start static NoSyn sleep
>   Start static NoSyn sleep
>   Start static NoSyn sleep
>   End static sleep
>   Start static sleep
>   End static NoSyn sleep
>   End static NoSyn sleep
>   End static NoSyn sleep
>   End static NoSyn sleep
>   End static NoSyn sleep
>   End static NoSyn sleep
>   End static NoSyn sleep
>   End static NoSyn sleep
>   End static NoSyn sleep
>   End static NoSyn sleep
>   End static sleep

Comment: A `static synchronized` method locks on the `Class` object for the class that declares the static method.  The answer to your question follows directly from that.

Comment: When A synchronized static method is locking class object, why the other static method can be invoked at the same time?

Comment: If the 2 methods are methods of the same class, then it can't.

Comment: please look at my code. Before "End static sleep" there are "Start static NoSyn sleep" printed.

Comment: Only one of the methods is `synchronized`.  Synchronization with mutexes only locks out other threads that are trying to synchronize using the same mutex.

Comment: you mean it only protect other threads accessed "the static synchronized methods" but "no static synchronized methods" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what you are asking now.

> If i invoke a synchronized static method, does it mean i lock this class and other method (including static or no static) can not be accessed before the synchronized static method end?

IF both methods are `synchronized` or use a `synchronized` block, AND they are synchronizing on the same thing (i.e. the same `Class` or the same `this`, THEN you will get mutual exclusion.

In your example, one method is not `synchronized` (and it doesn't use a `synchronized` block) so therefore, it will not be locked out.  In fact, nothing will lock out `staticSleepNoSyn` ... as you have written it.

Comment: I got it. The `synchronized` can not restraint the no `synchronized` Thank you~